# IEnumerable<object> a = new IEnumerable<object>(); Can I do this?

Tags: c#

I want to create a new instance of an object `IEnumerable<object>`

Can I do this?

```
IEnumerable<object> a = new IEnumerable<object>();
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191013/can-a-c-anonymous-class-implement-an-interface

Comment: Please clarify your question. That line of code won't compile, as I'm sure you've discovered already. If you could give us more information about what you're actually trying to achieve, that would help us to answer you.

Comment: I wanted to create a new enumerable object or list and be able to add to it.

Comment: @WingMan20-10: Well, that changes EVERYTHING. You can't add to a generic `IEnumerable<T>`. You have to use something like `List<T>`.

Comment: In this case you need a concrete array List<object> objs = new IEnumerable<object>. You cannot add items to an iterator because it's not a collection ... its an iterator:)

Comment: @ivo: Note that `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't represent an iterator - it represents an *iterable* sequence. `IEnumerator<T>` itself represents the iterator.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I'm aware of it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4514538/why-can-iterators-in-structs-modify-this/4571612#4571612 :) But don't want to confuse the person.

Comment: can ienumerable  deal with different datatypes of objects or same like IEnumerable<CompaniesDTO> need answer

Answer (score 162, accepted):

You can for example create an instance of `List<object>`, which implements `IEnumerable<object>`. Example:

```
List<object> list = new List<object>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(4);
list.Add(5);

IEnumerable<object> en = list;
CallFunction(en);
```

Comment: Given that the question shows the use of generics, given an example of a type that doesn't implement the generic `IEnumerable<T>` is a bad idea IMO.

Comment: Any problem with using CallFunction(list.AsEnumerable()) instead of IEnumerable<object> en = list;...

Comment: I'd use an array with literal initializer if possible, it's the most efficient and lightweight enumerable type available in .NET and doesn't have the overhead of a List<>. Lists should only be used if you really need or want to mutate after initialization. Also, it's better to add System.Linq and invoke .AsEnumerable() on the array or list.

Answer (score 75):

Another solution would be to use [`Empty<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

[msdn extract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> Returns an empty IEnumerable that has the specified type argument.

```
IEnumerable<object> a = Enumerable.Empty<object>();
```

There is a thread on SO about it: [Is it better to use Enumerable.Empty() as opposed to new List to initialize an IEnumerable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894038/is-it-better-to-use-enumerablet-empty-as-opposed-to-new-listt-to-initializ)

> If you use an empty array or empty list, those are objects and they are stored in memory. The Garbage Collector has to take care of them. If you are dealing with a high throughput application, it could be a noticeable impact.
>
> `Enumerable.Empty` does not create an object per call thus putting less load on the GC.

Comment: Cleanest answer!

Answer (score 36):

Since you now specified you want to add to it, what you want isn't a simple `IEnumerable<T>` but at least an `ICollection<T>`. I recommend simply using a `List<T>` like this:

```
List<object> myList=new List<object>();
myList.Add(1);
myList.Add(2);
myList.Add(3);
```

You can use myList everywhere an `IEnumerable<object>` is expected, since `List<object>` implements `IEnumerable<object>`.

**(old answer before clarification)**

You can't create an instance of `IEnumerable<T>` since it's a normal interface(It's sometimes possible to specify a default implementation, but that's usually used only with COM).

So what you really want is instantiate a *class* that implements the *interface* `IEnumerable<T>`. The behavior varies depending on which class you choose.

For an empty sequence use:

```
IEnumerable<object> e0=Enumerable.Empty<object>();
```

For an non empty enumerable you can use some collection that implements `IEnumerable<T>`. Common choices are the array `T[]`, `List<T>` or if you want immutability `ReadOnlyCollection<T>`.

```
IEnumerable<object> e1=new object[]{1,2,3};
IEnumerable<object> e2=new List<object>(){1,2,3};
IEnumerable<object> e3=new ReadOnlyCollection(new object[]{1,2,3});
```

Another common way to implement `IEnumerable<T>` is the [iterator feature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dscyy5s0.aspx) introduced in C# 3:

```
IEnumerable<object> MyIterator()
{
  yield return 1;
  yield return 2;
  yield return 3;
}

IEnumerable<object> e4=MyIterator();
```

Answer (score 32):

No you can't since `IEnumerable` is an interface.

You should be able to create an empty instance of most non-interface types which implement `IEnumerable`, e.g.:-

```
IEnumerable<object> a = new object[] { };
```

or

```
IEnumerable<object> a = new List<object>();
```

Comment: @AdamRalph: I downvoted, and then got distracted, so couldn't leave a comment immediately. Interfaces are types, so your answer is dangerously wrong because it propagates a common misconception.

Answer (score 11):

No, You cannot do that. Use the following line of code instead:

```
IEnumerable<int> usersIds = new List<int>() {1, 2, 3}.AsEnumerable();
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

The main reason is ***we can't create object of an interface, and IEnumerable is an interface***. 
We need to create object of the class which implements the interface. This is the main reason we can't directly create object of IEnumerable.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this:

```
IEnumerable<object> list = new List<object>(){1, 4, 5}.AsEnumerable();
CallFunction(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to create a new enumerable object or list and be able to add to it.

This comment changes everything. You can't add to a generic `IEnumerable<T>`. If you want to stay with the interfaces in `System.Collections.Generic`, you need to use a class that implements `ICollection<T>` like `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

I have been Implementing `IEnumerable` of type `IEnumerable<T>` by this way

```
IEnumerable<T> MyEnum = new T[]{ /*object of type T*/ };
```

Example:

```
var Object = new Book{id = 1,name = "Hello World"};
IEnumerable<Book> MyEnum = new Book[]{ Object };
```

Answer (score 0):

No IEnumerable is an interface, you can't create instance of interface

you can do something like this

```
IEnumerable<object> a = new object[0];
```

Comment: Is it possible to create instance of COM interface like that @Jon Skeet?

Comment: Absolutely. Weird, but true. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093536/how-does-the-c-compiler-detect-com-types and http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/07/07/faking-com-to-fool-the-c-compiler.aspx

Comment: I think it's possible to specify a default implementation that's instantiated instead of the interface for COM interfaces.

Comment: @JonSkeet isn't it more accurate to say that calling `new SomeComInterface()` instantiates the interface's associated "CoClass" rather than instantiating the interface itself?

Comment: @phoog: That would be accurate - but the important and odd thing is that you can use `new` with an interface in certain situations.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty old question, but for the sake of newcomers, this is how we can protect an `IEnumerable<T>` from a `null exception`. Another word, to create an empty instance of a variable of type `IEnumerable<T>`

```
public IEnumerable<T> MyPropertyName { get; set; } = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.empty?view=net-5.0

Cheers.