# Cast object to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, casting, ienumerable

```
object selectedDataItem;
MyClass.Inventory inventory;
inventory = (MyClass.Inventory) selectedDataItem;
```

in `inventory` we can see the details such as:

```
Trace.Writeline(inventory.Name + " " + inventory.Place);
```

You see inventory has inventory.Name, Inventory.Place I want to wrap all of the property inside IEnumerable or ObservableCollection so that I can iterate through all of the inventory at once and not by inventory.Name, inventory.Place etc etc...

How can I make inventory `IEnumerable` so that I can do something like this :

```
IEnumerable<MyClass.Inventory> enumerable = (IEnumerable<MyClass.Inventory>) inventory;
enumerable = from x in enumerable where x.Name == inventory.Name select x;
```

Right now if I do this the error is

> Unable to cast object of type 'MyClass.Inventory' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MyClass.Inventory]'.

Comment: Is 'selectedDataItem' a array or single Object ? If you want to convert single object to IEnumerable then, you should implement IEnumerable interface to 'Inventory' class.

Comment: `MyClass.Inventory` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<MyClass.Inventory>`. and it makes no sense for me why would you expect to cast single item to `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 14):

Just do this:

```
var enumerable = new [] { inventory };
```

Comment: That will compile but makes no sense.

Comment: The OP didn't ask if it made sense, just how to do it. :-)

Comment: That's the problem, what's the point of using IEnumerable when the data is just ONE object.

Comment: @Aniket - There is quite definitely a point. `IEnumerable<T>` can have zero or more objects, so defining an enumerable with a single object is useful as it can be filtered down to zero objects. And that's what the OP wants to do. This works even for value types. It then becomes somewhat equivalent to `Nullable<T>`. There are plenty of times when this is useful.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure why do you need this, but once i saw next extension method:

```
public static class CustomExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T input)
    {
        yield return input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`inventory` is an instance of class `MyClass.Inventory` and its not an enumerable list so that you can cast it directly. If you really want an enumerable with that object then you need to create an empty enumerable and add that object to it.

**Update**

You have to create a `List` first and add your object to that list, as,

```
List<MyClass.Inventory> lst = new List<MyClass.Inventory>();
lst.Add(inventory);
```

And then you can assign your list to the enumerable, as

```
IEnumerable<MyClass.Inventory> enumerable = lst;
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606407/ienumerableobject-a-new-ienumerableobject-can-i-do-this)

Comment: Creating an object of an interface?

Comment: `new IEnumerable<MyClass.Inventory>()` ?

Answer (score 1):

In general that would be a bad practice. If the data you're dealing with is not iterable, making it an `IEnumerable` makes no sense.

On the other hand, if you still want to use `IEnumerable<T>`, use `List<T>`, store your object in it, and then do the `LINQ` query!

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, so far this is the answer which addresses the core problem that *underlying type is not iteratable* +1