# Net Core: Declare and Initialize new Enumerable in Moq statement

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I am trying to declare and initialize an empty IEnumerable in a Moq statement. For some reason the last part where I try to declare ProductResult as Enumerable is failing. Can i do this inline with Moq statement?

```
mock.Setup(b => b.GetProductStatus(It.IsAny<bool>())).Returns(new List<ProductResult>().AsEnumerable() { });
```

Trying to research this article:

[IEnumerable<object> a = new IEnumerable<object>(); Can I do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606407/ienumerableobject-a-new-ienumerableobject-can-i-do-this)

Comment: u cant initialise an ienumerable. Its an interface

Comment: use `.Returns(Enumerable.Empty<ProductResult>())`

Comment: hi @Fenixil feel free to write in answer also, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You moq should look like this. No need to do AsEnumerable as List is an implementation of IEnumerable.

```
 mock.Setup(x => x.GetProductStatus(It.IsAny<bool>()))
.Returns(new List<ProductResult>());
```

You method I beleive looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<ProductResult> GetProductStatus(bool someValue);
```

With a list you can do things like Count, Linq Any etc.

For further info, Quickstart is a good reference. Link here: 
https://code.google.com/archive/p/moq/wikis/QuickStart.wiki

Answer (score 0):

I can only make a wild guess with this limited info.
Can you please remove `.AsEnumerable() { }` and see?

1. The {} is odd and it's not proper C# code.
2. List implements IEnumerable so you don't need the .AsEnumerable()

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to return empty `IEnumerable` you can use [Enumerable.Empty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.empty?view=netframework-4.8). If you need non empty collection, then you can return any, because all of them implement `IEnumerable`.

```
.Returns(Enumerable.Empty<ProductResult>())
.Returns(new[] {1, 2, 3})
```