# Why do I have to copy "this" when using LINQ in a struct (and is it OK if I do)?

Tags: c#, linq, struct

The code belows contains a simple LINQ query inside an immutable struct.

```
struct Point
{
   static readonly List</*enum*/> NeighborIndexes;
   //and other readonly fields!

    public IEnumerable<FlatRhombPoint> GetEdges()
    {
        return from neighborIndex in NeighborIndexes;
             select GetEdge(neighborIndex);
    }
}
```

It does not compile.

> Anonymous methods, lambda expressions, and query expressions inside
>   structs cannot access instance members of 'this'. Consider copying
>   'this' to a local variable outside the anonymous method, lambda
>   expression or query expression and using the local instead.

**Does any one know why this is not allowed?**

The fix the message suggests works fine:

```
    public IEnumerable<FlatRhombPoint> GetEdges()
    {
        var thisCopy = this;

        return from neighborIndex in NeighborIndexes;
             select thisCopy.GetEdge(neighborIndex);
    }
```

But is this standard practice? Are there reasons for not having queries like this in structs?
(In the bigger scheme of things making a copy does not worry me performance-wise as such).

Comment: Why not just use select this.GetEdge(neighborIndex);?

Comment: @antinescience, they explain in the question that they get an error when using `this`.

Comment: I should probably read more carefully. Bleh.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4514538/34397

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instance methods on structs are called with a *reference* to `this` – [a hidden `ref` parameter](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/when-can-you-write-ref-this.html).
This is why struct methods are able to mutate the structs they're called on.

When you use `this` (or any other local variable / parameter) inside a lambda expression or LINQ query, the compiler turns it into a field on a [compiler-generate closure class](http://blog.slaks.net/2011/06/delegates-vs-function-pointers-part-4-c.html).

The CLR does not support `ref` fields, so it would be impossible for the captured `this` to work the same way as a regular `this`.  (this is also the reason that you can't use `ref` parameters inside lambdas)

Iterator methods have the same issue – they are compiled into a hidden enumerator class, and all variables or parameters become fields in the class (this is why iterators cannot take `ref` parameters).
However, for iterators, C# made the opposite decision.  Inside an iterator, you [can use `this`](http://blog.slaks.net/2010/12/when-shouldnt-you-write-ref-this.html), but it will be copied to a field on the enumerator class.
This means that if you mutate a struct inside an iterator, the mutations will not happen to the caller's copy.